# [Solved]Javascript/Jquery & PHP: getting div ID that's in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Solved: the answer was so simple. I needed to pass the variable into the function but the other coding was helpful. Thanks, all.

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

foreach($array as $key=>$info)
{
  echo "<form action = 'form' method = 'post'>
  <select name = 'choice' onChange = 'changeFunc()'>
    <option value = 'first'>first</option>
  </select>
  <input type = 'submit' value = 'send'></form>

  <div name = 'getID' id = '$key'>  </div>";
}


function changeFunc() 
{
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('getID');
  var key = elements[0].getAttribute('id');
}
```

So what's happening is that when I try to get the ID of the div that's in the loop, the default answer is the first loop. I'm not quite sure what the logic is to get individual divs that were created in the loop.

Comment: Why not just add the key to your JS function call? `onChange = 'changeFunc(\"$key\")'`

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Sorry for being so dumb about something so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Since tagged with jQuery... I suggest you a `change` event handler for all `select` that has a `name="choice"` that will find the `id` of the div `.getID` withing its closest `form`.

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

foreach($array as $key=>$info){
  echo "<form action='form' method='post'>
  <select name='choice'>
    <option value='first'>first</option> <!-- You probably need more than one option if you expect a change event ;) -->
  </select>
  <input type='submit' value='send'>
  </form>
  <div class='getID' id='$key'></div>"; // A class here instead of a name.
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select[name='choice']").on("change", function(){
    var key = $(this).closest("form").find(".getID")[0].id
    console.log("Select changed... Here is the key:", key)
  });
});

// The same in plain JS
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  document.querySelectorAll("select[name='choice']").forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener("change", function(){
      var key = this.closest("form").querySelector(".getID").id
      console.log("Select changed... Here is the key:", key)
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think,

`document.getElementsByClassName('getID')` => you get 3 elements

then `elements[0].getAttribute('id')` => you get first element

That is why you always get the first element id,
you can use this to get individual divs.

```js
    function changeFunc() 
    {
    var element = this.closest("form").getElementsByClassName('getID');
    var key = element.getAttribute('id');
    
    }
```